# No Data value with D3

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I am using D3.js for drawing lines:

[0,10,20,15,20,10,15,5]

[image: img 1]

But how to use null values ? for example:

[0,10,20,null,null,10,15,5]

[image: img 2]

Comment: loop through data and check if null, if it is null don't draw it. may have to draw multiple lines

Comment: or draw multiple lines to start with and check if the start or end point is null dont draw that line

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider using the built-in line generator [`d3.svg.line()`](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/SVG-Shapes#line). By providing an appropriate accessor function to [`line.defined()`](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/SVG-Shapes#line_defined) you can specify where the line is defined and how to handle your `null` values:

> The defined accessor can be used to define where the line is defined
>   and undefined, which is typically useful in conjunction with missing
>   data; the generated path data will automatically be broken into
>   multiple distinct subpaths, skipping undefined data.

Note, however, that the line generator by default assumes your data is provided as a two-dimensional array, but you could easily map your input array accordingly or provide appropriate accessor functions to `line.x()` and `line.y()`.

Comment: .defined(function(d) {return !isNaN(d);})